# Image under another image not shown Android

Tags: android, xml

Hi I wanna implement following picture

When I go to XML-design of android studio it's exactly what I want but when I run app the straight line under the circle not shown Can any body give me some hint to solve this issue ? ( I also use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout but not worked )

**Edit :** In fact my problem is RelativeLayout which contains straight line not as height as other RelativeLayout. Does anyone knows how to solve this  ?!

**Edit 2:** I change relativeLayout of parent to LinearLayout and it's worked ! I dont know why but it's work !

Here is my row of list after some changes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_area_radius"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/half_circle_area_radius"
            android:background="@color/orange" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_area_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_area_radius"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />


        <com.mycompany.ui.customui.PersianTextView
            android:id="@+id/araNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="1299"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- our content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pager_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_padding_large"
        android:background="@drawable/balloon_incoming_normal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mycompany.ui.customui.PersianTextView
            android:id="@+id/itemText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/global_padding_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_padding"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/global_padding_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_padding_large"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_padding"
            android:background="@color/gray_20" />

        <com.mycompany.ui.customui.IconTextView
            android:id="@+id/favoriteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/global_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_padding"
            android:text="@string/icon_star_empty"
            android:textColor="@color/black_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_smaller" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: does your Orange box seems to cover the whole width in the output? Please provide the screen shot of the one with error.

Comment: @Mayank Thanks for your reply I added screen-shot

Comment: @Mayank if I set layout_height to xxx the straight line appears but when I set it to match_parent or fill_parent its not shown and its under the circle

Answer (score 1):

The thing is line might actually form, but you are not able to see it, because it's behind the circle. If I'm right, test it by adding this to the circle `android:alpha="20"`. The line could be seen behind the circle. If that works the solution below should work.

1. Change the fill_parent to match_parent, fill_parent is deprecated.

Since you use match_parent in the first layout.

The solution could be this

Better Implementation would be using this:

```
| Circle(V1) | TextView with information(V2) |
```

Align V1 to left and top (with circle and line as center of the layout).
Align V2 to the right of V1.

**EDIT**

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">


         <!-- this is my straight line -->
         <ImageView 
             android:layout_width="3dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
             android:src="#f6802e" />
```

Your line's height matches parent's height, change

```
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

to

```
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**EDIT #2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00aaaaaa"
        android:paddingLeft="65sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="3sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#aa00aa"
            android:paddingLeft="65sp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="65sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:paddingLeft="65sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65sp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above code runs and gives you the desired output as well, just replace the imageViews(Also the first RelativeLayout is unnecessary, inflating them takes memory). [Here's the screenshot](http://i59.tinypic.com/ztuio6.jpg).

Comment: My problem is not visibility the straight line is visible but its under the circle so I cant see it. The height of line is same as my circle ! The problem is Height of two relativeLayout it's not the same

Comment: did you replace fill_parent with match_parent

Comment: Then try to set the alignment of this layout relative to the previous layout, like I describe it in my answer. your code seems fine

Comment: not unfortunately , but I change my code and put them inside LinearLayout and works ! I don't know why !

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
                android:src="#f6802e" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/circle"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
                android:src="@drawable/circle" />
```